# How to load the tree panel tree store with Ajax response

Tags: extjs, extjs4

How to load the tree panel tree store with Ajax response.

How to load the tree panel tree store with Ajax response json.

i can load it locally , i.e. if i have the json file locally available then i can load it through configured proxy by using treeStore.load() method.

But now if i have the data from a Ajax response then how can i do that?

Model :

```
Ext.define('dimExpModel', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
fields : [
{
    name: 'memberName'
},
{
    name: 'memberCode'
},
{
    name: 'dimension'
}
]
});
```

Store :

```
var dimExpStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore',{
         storeId:'dimExpStore',
         model:dimExpModel,
         proxy: {
                    type: 'memory',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json'
                    }
                }

    });
```

Tree Panel :

```
{
"xtype": "treepanel",
"height": 250,
"id": "treePanel",
"width":400,
"title":"My Tree Panel",
"store": "dimExpStore",
"displayField":"memberName",
"useArrows":true,
"viewConfig": {

}
};
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

T would do it like this:

```
{
"xtype": "treepanel",
"height": 250,
"id": "treePanel",
"width":400,
"title":"My Tree Panel",
"rootVisible":false,
"store":{autoLoad:true,"fields":[{"name":"id",type:"string"},
{"name":"memberName","type":"string"},{"name":"memberCode","type":"string"},
{"name":"memberCode","type":"dimension"}],
proxy:{type:'ajax',url:'json.php'},root:{text:"Members","id":"src","expanded":true}}
"displayField":"memberName",
"useArrows":true,
"viewConfig": {

}
};
```

In my example `json.php` returs the desired json in a correct form.

**Edit**
Take a look at "id" param inside `root` block. Each time when you click on tree nodes containing children, at the server side you should form a correct response depending on that "id" which is actually id_parent of all those children nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i cannot give url to store ,  since i do not have any page which gives me the json. rather i simply have a ajax call to database which returns me the json form oracle database.

Comment: If json is returned not as an object, then do Ext.decode(returnedValue,1) and try to play width methods like add, insert, update or something like that - just look in documentation for the appropriate one.

Comment: i can surely make the object of Ajax response dear , but tree store does not provide a method to add or insert or update the store data , right now i am doing it with treeStore.setRootNode({}); and it is working, but i was looking for some load method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your store proxy as ajax and call store.load()

```
var dimExpStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore',{
     storeId:'dimExpStore',
     model:dimExpModel,
     proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'users.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'records',
            totalProperty:  'recordCount',
            successProperty: 'success'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i cannot configure the store like this. rather i have a ajax call to database which gives me the json. so my problem is to add that json to store.

Comment: Then make an AJAX request and in the reponse add the data to store, some thing like below Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: uri,method: 'POST',
        success:function(response) { //read the response and then add the data to the store by using store.add({});
        },
        failure: function(response) {}
    });

Comment: i can do the addition of data with json store , but tree store does not provide the add method on it. right now i am doing it with setRootNode({});